# Merge and replace a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = {'Date':[np.nan, "20/10/2020", np.nan, "20/12/2001", np.nan,"12/03/2020",np.nan, "20/10/2020"],
    'ART1':[np.nan, "WER", np.nan, 65, np.nan, 76,np.nan, 76],
    'PTOS':["F", np.nan, 43, np.nan,  56, "K","L", np.nan],
   'TPR':[np.nan, 45, np.nan, 65, np.nan, 54, np.nan, 45], 
   'ART':[np.nan, 76, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 15,np.nan, 16], 
   'ARfT':[np.nan, 15, np.nan, 18, np.nan,29,np.nan, 15,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is what I need

```
data = {'Date':["20/10/2020", "20/12/2001","12/03/2020", "20/10/2020"],
    'ART1':["WER", 65,  76, 76],
    'PTOS':["F", 43, "56 K", "L"],
   'TPR':[45, 65,  54,45], 
   'ART':[76,  np.nan,  15, 16], 
   'ARfT':[15, 18, 29, 15]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I need to merge the rows and after I can remove the row with NAN.

I tried this one, but it does not replace the rows

```
df.iloc[1] = df.iloc[0].combine_first(df.iloc[1]),
```

but it does not replace the rows in df and there are a conflict when merging numbers and strings. Does anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: What's the criteria to concat `56` with `K` ?  You want to merge every 2 rows and if both rows have values, concat them ?

Comment: In this case, row 0  - has only one value in PTOS column, and this value F should be in row 1.  Also, in row 4 and 5 both have values for PTOS, so I need to keep both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option via [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate):

```
b = df['Date'].bfill()
df1 = (
    df.groupby([b, b.ne(b.shift()).cumsum()], sort=False, as_index=False)
        .aggregate(lambda c: ' '.join(c.dropna().astype(str)) or np.nan)
)
```

`df1`:

```
         Date ART1  PTOS   TPR   ART  ARfT
0  20/10/2020  WER     F  45.0  76.0  15.0
1  20/12/2001   65    43  65.0   NaN  18.0
2  12/03/2020   76  56 K  54.0  15.0  29.0
3  20/10/2020   76     L  45.0  16.0  15.0
```

Comment: This would be quite good solution, the problem is that there might be more than 1 record for date, and other columns also can have more than 1 entry

Comment: I don't understand. This should handle all records with the same Date, and it combines as many entries that exist in every column. The only thing this wouldn't handle well would be nested lists. Is that what you're talking about?/Can you provide an example where this does not produce the expected output?

Comment: I updated the example - basically, the date is not unique, and if I apply I will have 2 separated rows in one

Comment: @RandyMorrison updated to treat separated same dates as separate groups.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = (
    df.groupby(df.Date.bfill(), sort=False, as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: ' '.join(y.dropna().astype(str))))
)
```

Alternative:

```
df = (
    df.set_index(df['Date'].bfill())
    .stack()
    .astype(str)
    .groupby(level=[0, 1], sort = False)
    .agg(' '.join)
    .unstack(-1)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
         Date ART1  PTOS   TPR   ART  ARfT
0  20/10/2020  WER     F  45.0  76.0  15.0
1  20/12/2001   65    43  65.0        18.0
2  12/03/2020   76  56 K  54.0  15.0  29.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Nk03, I also updated an example - the problem is that I do not have a unique column